# how to set spinner selection by text inside it

Tags: android, android-spinner

I preparing a form in which i have to use same page for Adding details and Editing details. While adding details all fields will be blank and spinner selection will be set to "no selection".
Now i want to set the spinner selection of the item which i am going to pass from the previous activity. How to achieve this ??
As spinner does not have any method something like, *setSelection(String string);*
Or is there any other way, i can achieve this mechanism...

Would anyone please help me...

Comment: spinner is subClass of AbsSpinner and AbsSpinner has a method setSelection http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int, boolean)

Comment: @nidhi_adiga. Ya thats right. But i need to set spinner selection by name not by id, as i wont have id of the text i want to pass to setSelection(int position);.

Comment: Hey can i do like this ??  category_spinner.setSelection(category_spinner_array_list.indexOf("cat_name"));

Comment: Ya if u get the expected output...

Comment: @nidhi_adiga. Yup. i am getting the desired output. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: post what u have tried,..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont now how frequently this might be used but we can set selection of the spinner by text inside it.
Spinner has the method *setSelection(int position);*.

Now in the parameter we need to pass position of the text, which we can get from the array_list we use to bind to adapter, by `getIndexOf(Object object)` and object should be of the type of `ArrayList` that is declared For example, if `ArrayList` is of type String, the object to be passed to `getIndexOf(Object object)` should be of type String.

Finally, you set selection as below:

```
spinner.setSelection ( spinner_array_list.indexOf(string) );
```

Answer (score 17):

This is what i did and it seems to work fine

```
Spinner my_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn_items);
ArrayAdapter<String> array_spinner=(ArrayAdapter<String>)my_spinner.getAdapter();
    my_spinner.setSelection(array_spinner.getPosition("list item"));
```