# How to keep a value selected in android spinner based on database value?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have populated an android spinner from database in one activity.
But on the edit part of activity I wanna keep the android spinner selected to particular value equivalent to current record.
When I use

```
spinner.setSelection(keepSelectedStateID);
```

It keeps it selected by position I wanna keep it selected by ID or value based from record in db.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: have you tried above line in your code.??

Comment: Yes I have tried but it gives selected for that position and not for the value which is in DB

Comment: Use a switch case, assign values(0,1,2) to DB values(String/ID).

Comment: Check my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15675153/1739882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method after poputlating spinner. pass spinner and value to this method.

```
public static void setSpinnerValue(Spinner spin, String value) {

    for (int i = 0; i < spin.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spin.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            spin.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
```

//set the default according to value

```
mySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition)
```

Comment: what is "myAdap"... List Adapter object?